# Is there is a way to convert the postman collections into BDD cucumber or Karate script directly?

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, karate

I am doing some API Testing using Postman and I am trying that in BDD Cucumber and Karate framework. Is there is any way to convert the postman collections into BDDC Cucumber or Karate script directly.

Comment: please refer: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1498673214666719233 - note that this is commercial. if interested, please get in touch

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas,Yes we are interested in doing the POC for converting the Postman collection into karate script. If any demo or solution is available please let us know on the same.

Comment: can you use the contact form at https://karatelabs.io and we will get in touch